# Sugar on floor wet mopped

Tags: cleaning, food, kitchen

I spilled sugar on the floor and I was in half sleep. Later, I used my "Swiffer" with its fluid to get it up. But after that, the floor became sticky. So I steam mopped it twice and it's still sticky. Please help me with any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Adding up two solutions for you:

FIRST SOLUTION

- You can make a little heap with the sugar, and then with a sheet of paper you try to push the sheet under the heap to get the sugar.
- It's not a perfect solution, there is probably sugar remaining but now you can reuse a part of the sugar.

SECOND SOLUTION:

1. Fill a bucket with warm water. Use hot water for really sticky situations.
2. Add the appropriate amount of floor cleaner that is recommended on the packaging.
3. Moisten the mop with the cleaning solution. Clean the floor thoroughly and rinse the mop frequently.
4. Dump out the bucket and fill with clean water.
5. Rinse the floor completely with clean water. If there is cleaning residue left on the floor, it can be sticky as well and make it seem that the original spill was not cleaned up.
6. If the sticky floor remains, fill a bucket with warm or hot water and add ½ cup of household ammonia.
7. Moisten the mop with the water and clean the entire area. Dump out the ammonia and water.
8. Fill the bucket again and add 1 cup of white vinegar.
9. Use the vinegar to rinse the floor. Allow the floor to air dry or dry with old towels. If any sticky areas remain, repeat the above steps to remove
   the remaining stickiness.

Comment: The "First Solution" seems moot since the question is how to remove the sticky mess left behind by the wet Swiffer — and ewww, I hope folks aren't serving food swept off the floor. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdiG3pSavqU.

Answer (score 2):

**Dogs** are usually more than willing to help out with this kind of problem (applicable to *other foods dropped on the floor* too).

You don't really need to do anything apart from giving the dog access to the respective area. After the dog is done, a simple application of your standard floor cleaning procedure can be applied as required.

They even make a surprising good effort on carpets, as they try to extract the last bit of flavour.

As dog owner you should know yourself which human food items dogs should not eat. Sugar in a rare occasion, in smaller quantities, is definitely ok.

If you need to ask a neighbour for their pet, explain to them exactly what the food is; they should be able to tell if it is a problem for the dog (or for them).

Obviously don't apply this hack if you had a go at the floor with any kind of cleaning products or chemicals.

Comment: A bit more broadly, **saliva** in general will break down food remains. That's what it's created for in the first place.

Comment: @Flater thanks for the mental image of the OP crawling around, licking their floor...? <shudder>

Comment: @Stephie: I doubt the OP can't spit nor wet a wipe with saliva.

Answer (score 2):

You need a mop that can be squeezed or wrung out. Mop with clear water, squeeze into a bucket, repeat, repeat, repeat, ... until not sticky.